# little hope means no hope?

Tags: determiners

I know `little` or `few` means `almost none` or `not as much as may be expected`.

What is the meaning of the following sentence:

> I have little hope.

Does it mean no hope?

Comment: You state in your first sentence what you know *little* to mean. So, why are you asking something that contradicts that knowledge?

Answer (score 5):

No, it means:

> I have only a small amount of hope.

or

> I have almost no hope.